Which was that movie featuring girls fleeing their guardian?
I remember watching this TV movie (on a children's channel so it was clean). This was at least 4 years ago. There were a few (3-4) girls (or sisters). They try to escape their mean male guardian. I remember a scene when the girls are running away into the forest and their guardian tries shooting at them. I remember there was a small girl, about 7 or 8.
The girls wore frocks so I guess the year was pre-1970. 
Sorry I can't be more specific.
The girls were all under 18.

rabbit proof fence? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0252444/?ref_=nv_sr_3

No, all the girls were white. Also it seems to me that the movie was set in Europe rather than USA.

The guardian was an older man(30s-40s) with a moustache and a hat, dressed very stylishly.

I got it, it is Courage Mountain featuring a grown up Heidi.

